# How to translate django model field's help_text with variable

Tags: python, django, internationalization

models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFiled(help_text=_("Name cannot contain %s") % settings.SPECIAL_CHARS)
```

django.po:

```
msgid "Name cannot contain %s"
msgstr "xxxxx"
```

Not working.
How to use gettext in django model field's help_text with variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to do it but there is documentation about it, if nobody answers you can find an answer from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/). And a tutorial [here](https://testdriven.io/blog/multiple-languages-in-django/)